# Print only one zero from the leading zeros in python

Tags: python, leading-zero

I have the following task, take number from input, extend it to 12 digits and then print billions, millions, thousands, hundreds and unit. I have split the number to corresponding parts as string. The code follows:

```
num = input("Please enter a number: ")
num = str(num)

zero = num.zfill(12)

billion = zero[0:3]
million = zero[3:6]
thousand = zero[6:9]
hundred = zero[9:10]
unit = zero[10:]
```

Suppose, the num is 63380.

Expected output

```
0 billion 0 million 63 thousand 3 hundred and 80
```

But I get

```
000 billion 000 million 063 thousand 3 hundred and 80
```

Comment: Is the homework question to print a number in words, or print the number with a single leading zero, as the headline implies?

Comment: ...and if it _is_ a homework question, can you show us the effort you have already put in before posting here?

Comment: You could convert your `000` string back to an `int`: `int(billion)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it is a homework question. The question was to print out the user input into measurement segments: billion, million, thousand, hundred and units. I have tried the above codes, and this is how far I could get.

Comment: @stolenmoment the output should include only one zero if there are no numbers present for that measurement segment. 
Such as, the user input is 1999, then i should print out 0 Bilion, 0 Million, 1 Thousand, 9 hundred and 99. 
Hope I was able to explain.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your `zero` string to `int()` like this

```py
num = input("Please enter a number: ")
num = str(num)

zero = num.zfill(12)

billion = int(zero[0:3])
million = int(zero[3:6])
thousand = int(zero[6:9])
hundred = int(zero[9:10])
unit = int(zero[10:])

print(billion ,'billion', million ,'million', thousand , 'thousand' , hundred , 'hundred and' , unit)
```

converting into int do this.
`3.7` to `3` `'3'` to `3` and `000000000003` to `3` and `00000` to `0`.
it deletes many zeros in the front of the numbers and convert string to int.
and float(like `3.7`) to int(to `3`) by discarding it.

Comment: This worked. But could you please explain why I have to convert it to integer?

Comment: Understood. Thankyou so much.

Comment: I'm glad It helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to control the decimals.

```
num = 63380

dict = {
9:'billion',
6:'million',
3:'thousand',
2:'hundred',
0:' '
}
for key, item in dict.items():
    n=num//10**key
    print(n,item,end =' ') 
    num-=n*10**key
```

Output:

```
0 billion 0 million 63 thousand 3 hundred 80
```